# How can I convert my script for submitting SLURM jobs from Bash to Perl?

Tags: bash, perl, slurm

I have the following Bash script for job submission to [SLURM](https://computing.llnl.gov/linux/slurm/) on a cluster:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -A 1234
#SBATCH -t 2-00:00 
#SBATCH -n 24

module add xxx
srun resp.com
```

The `#SBATCH` lines are SLURM commands:

- `#SBATCH -A 1234` is the project number (1234)
- `#SBATCH -t 2-00:00` is the job time
- `#SBATCH -n 24` is the number of cores

`module add xxx` loads the [Environment Module](http://modules.sourceforge.net/) `xxx` (in this case I'm actually using `module add gaussian`, where `gaussian` is a computational quantum-chemistry program).

`srun` is the SLURM command to launch a job. `resp.com` includes commands for gaussian and atom coordinates.

I tried converting the Bash script to the following Perl script, but it didn't work. How can I do this in Perl?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

system ("#SBATCH -A 1234");
system ("#SBATCH -t 2-00:00");
system ("#SBATCH -n 24");

system ("module add xxx");
system ("srun resp.com ");
```

Comment: What is your `$SHELL` environment variable set to? Also, #'s are comments... why are you executing those?

Comment: Are `module` and `srun` binaries/commands or shell functions/etc.?

Comment: Also calling this a "conversion" is a bit of a strong term. Are you planning to do something else with this perl script such that doing this "conversion" has a purpose?

Comment: @RyanJ, `system` just uses `/bin/sh` on Unix systems, not the user's shell.

Comment: Calling `system 'module', 'add', 'xxx'` or `system qw(module add xxx)` will be more efficient than calling system() with a single string. Passing a list of words instead of a single string means that perl does not have to parse the string and decide whether pass it to  /bin/sh instead of invoking the command directly.

Comment: @glennjackman yes, correct. From documentation: "If there is only one scalar argument, the argument is checked for shell metacharacters, and if there are any, the entire argument is passed to the system's command shell for parsing (this is /bin/sh -c on Unix platforms, but varies on other platforms)"

Comment: It appears that your script is for job submission to SLURM (or some other batch processing system that uses sbatch).  The #SBATCH lines aren't commands that are run by the shell or can be executed by system().  They are options that are parsed by sbatch.  You should be able to leave them as regular comments and sbatch will do the right thing.  However, you're still not going to get what you want.  The module command is a cluster command that is for setting up shell environment variables -- it's not going to do the right thing for perl.

Comment: Yes. My script is for job submission to SLURM on cluster. I have to use #SBATCH lines because they are for jobtime, the number of cores, project name... And I will run a lot of job using this script on cluster.  Unfortunately I couldnt find any useful thing about running perl script to SLURM on internet. That is very strange.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not helpful. What happened that you did not expect? What did you expect to happen, but didn't?

Comment: Not sure about `srun`, but the Perl module [`Env::Modulecmd`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Env::Modulecmd) will let you load [Environment Modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net/): the shell command `module load foo/1.0` becomes `use Env::Modulecmd { load => 'foo/1.0' };` in Perl.

Answer (score 3):

Each of your `system` calls creates a child process to run the program in question and returns when the child process dies.

The whole point of `module` is to configure the current shell by, among other things, modifying it's environment.  When this process completes (dies) say goodbye to those changes.  The call to `srun`, in it's shinny new process with a shinny new environment, hasn't got a chance.

Steps forward:

- Understand SLURM & bash and *exactly* why `system("#SBATCH whatever");` might not be of *any* value.  Hint: `#` marks the beginning of a comment in both Bash & Perl.
- Understand what `module add` is doing with `xxx` and how you might replicate what it's doing inside the shell within the Perl interpreter.  ThisSuitIsBlackNot recommends `use Env::Modulecmd { load => 'foo/1.0' };` to replicate this functionality.
- Barring any understanding of `module add`, `system ('module add xxx; srun resp.com')` would put those two commands in the same shell process, but at this point you need to ask yourself what you've gained by adding a Perl interpreter to the mix.

Comment: You've not made it clear what you're trying to accomplish with this Perl "conversion", but my advice is to understand *completely* what your shell script is doing, how it is being done, and exactly what part SLURM is playing in it.  Only then will you, or anyone, be able to formulate a plan that works around abandoning this script's single shell architecture.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is write

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

#SBATCH -A 1234
#SBATCH -t 2-00:00
#SBATCH -n 24

use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

system ("module add xxx && srun resp.com ");
```

and then submit it with

```
sbatch my_perl_script.pl
```

The `#SBATCH` lines are comments destined to be parsed by the `sbatch` command. They must be comments in the submission script.

The `module` command modifies the environment, but that environment is lost as soon as it is called if you invoke it with `system` on its own as `system` creates a subshell. You need to either invoke it on the same subshell as `srun`, as shown above, or use Perl tools to load the module in the environment of the Perl script so that it is available to `srun`, using `use Env::Modulecmd { load => 'foo/1.0' };` as mentioned elsewhere.